# Laravel-Predis SSL issues - stream_socket_enable_crypto() fails after moving to a newer version of Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, predis

We have a service running a Laravel app on an EC2 server with an ubuntu 18.04 image on it. We're trying to upgrade the OS to Ubuntu 22.04. Laravel version is 5.3, PHP version is 7.1.

After installing the necessary software and pre-requisits just like we do on our current server, connecting to our redis cluster fails with this error:

```
[ErrorException]
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error:
```

and in the `laravel.log` file:

```
[2023-06-25 13:02:01] production.ERROR: ErrorException: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error in /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:246
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'stream_socket_e...', '/home/ubuntu/ve...', 246, Array)
#1 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(246): stream_socket_enable_crypto(Resource id #520, true, 9)
#2 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(107): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->tlsStreamInitializer(Object(Predis\Connection\Parameters))
#3 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(81): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->createResource()
#4 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(258): Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->connect()
#5 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(157): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->connect()
#6 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(288): Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->getResource()
#7 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php(395): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->write('*2\r\n$3\r\nGET\r\n$3...')
#8 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(110): Predis\Connection\StreamConnection->writeRequest(Object(Predis\Command\Redis\GET))
#9 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(341): Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\Redis\GET))
#10 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php(324): Predis\Client->executeCommand(Object(Predis\Command\Redis\GET))
#11 /home/ubuntu/app/app/Containers/RedisReplica.php(23): Predis\Client->__call('get', Array)
#12 /home/ubuntu/app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(6468): App\Containers\RedisReplica->get('pricing_checked...')
#13 /home/ubuntu/app/app/Helpers/CacheHelper.php(171): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('get', Array)
#14 /home/ubuntu/app/app/Console/Commands/Tests/TestCommand.php(920): App\Helpers\CacheHelper::getPricingCheckedForListing(1)
#15 /home/ubuntu/app/app/Console/Commands/Tests/TestCommand.php(135): App\Console\Commands\Tests\TestCommand->cacheReplica()
#16 [internal function]: App\Console\Commands\Tests\TestCommand->handle()
#17 /home/ubuntu/app/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(1375): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#19 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(261): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(817): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(App\Console\Commands\Tests\TestCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /home/ubuntu/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /home/ubuntu/app/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 {main}
```

Our configuration is pretty basic:

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

    'default' => [
        'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME','tls'),
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'somehost'),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', 'somepassword')
    ],

    'replica' => [
        'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME','tls'),
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST_REPLICA', 'somehost'),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', 'somepassword')
    ],

    'options' => [
        'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
        'ssl'    => ['verify_peer' => false],
    ]
    
],
```

I can't really make heads or tails here. Obviously we're using pretty old versions of these tools, sure, but how does this create an issue like that? All I can find online is people facing this issue when using their mail service, but nothing about predis. help

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/19867. Literally googled `error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal`, do it, you will find more solutions

Comment: @matiaslauriti yeah I found a lot of different conversations about these sort of errors, but I'll be honest I don't really understand them, how they relate to my case or how to apply their solutions in my situation.

Comment: Most of them are talking about your OS using an old OpenSSL installation, or the server you want to talk to, does not support newer TLS versions, hence the error. If it is the second case, they will share what parameters to add so it uses the old TLS version (TLSv1), but I am very ignorant about it right now

Comment: @matiaslauriti yeah eventually I figured it out, the new servers are using OpenSSL3 while the old ones used OpenSSL1 and we're using pretty old software by now. I tried installing both OpenSSL versions alongside but it's a mess. Unless someone has some clever solution we'll just have to completely revamp our system I guess